# Data from textarea with line breaks to database

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, angularjs

I have a simple textarea. Once a save button is clicked, I save that data using an angular controller. Then once an update button is clicked, I update a row in that data base, that one of that rows fields is the data from that textarea.

So far so good, and the update is done ok, the problem begins when I break lines in the textarea, for example, I type:

> "Hi,↵This is another row"

I checked that data and when I save it in the controller, and when I get it back from the server it looks like this: "Hi,↵This is another row".

Seems ok, but when I place it inside a div I get the following:

> "Hi,This is another row"

Where did the line break go? and why is it not displaying?

I tried bunch of things, like changing the newline to `<br>` once send to the database, later on switching it back to newline, nothing seems to work.

Comment: Html is rendered in a way that all whitespace is replaced by one space by default, except for pre tags and inside textarea.

Answer (score 4):

Okay - what you need to do is use `white-space:pre-wrap;` where you display the data from the database.

Example:

```
<?php
echo '<p style="white-space:pre-wrap;">'.$yourVarWithWhiteSpace.'</p>';
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use this

```
<?php
echo '<p>'. nl2br($yourVarWithWhiteSpace).'</p>';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can programatically change the \n line ending with a `<br />` tag on the way in or out. By using prepared statements the need for using something like real_escape_string is handled for you.

That said, using @itamar 's method is probably better in the long term.